# trying to install react-native-android-widget but after installation build fails

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, android-widget

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-android-widget'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-android-widget:classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find lint-model-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.2.1).     Searched in the following locations:
> ...   > Could not find builder-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find manifest-merger-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find sdk-common-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find sdklib-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find repository-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find gradle-api-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find builder-test-api-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find ddmlib-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find aaptcompiler-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find aapt2-proto-7.2.1-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.2.1-7984345).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find crash-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find tracker-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find shared-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find lint-typedef-remover-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-typedef-remover:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.2.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find databinding-common-7.2.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find baseLibrary-7.2.1.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find layoutlib-api-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.2.1.jar
> (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.2.1).     Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...   > Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find builder-model-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find dvlib-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find common-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find apkzlib-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find protos-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...
> Could not find signflinger-7.2.1.jar (com.android:signflinger:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/7.2.1/signflinger-7.2.1.jar
> Could not find zipflinger-7.2.1.jar (com.android:zipflinger:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/7.2.1/zipflinger-7.2.1.jar
> Could not find annotations-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:30.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> ...   > Could not find apksig-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.2.1).
> Searched in the following locations:

Everything works fine but after i install "react-native-android-widget" it just doesnt build and run the app and the ubove error keeps showing up. I tried changing the gradle version to 7.2.1 as it suggests in the log but it still is the same as before with same error log. I even tried using vpn while building to make sure if there where any network accessibility issue.